# ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 32, saw 2

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to access the John Hopkins COVID Dataset through github. However it is Showing the following Error:

**CODE**

```
import pandas as pd

data_url = 'https://github.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/blob/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_time_series/time_series_covid19_confirmed_global.csv'

data = pd.read_csv(data_url)

print(data.head()
```

**ERROR:**

```
ParserError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-31-7b8cf362c9e9> in <module>()
      1 data_url = 'https://github.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/blob/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_time_series/time_series_covid19_confirmed_global.csv'
----> 2 data = pd.read_csv(data_url,encoding = "ISO-8859-1")
      3 data.head()

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in read(self, nrows)
   2035     def read(self, nrows=None):
   2036         try:
-> 2037             data = self._reader.read(nrows)
   2038         except StopIteration:
   2039             if self._first_chunk:

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.read()

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_low_memory()

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_rows()

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._tokenize_rows()

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.raise_parser_error()

ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 32, saw 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Yeah so that link is to the github page, which is html and everything as well as the csv file.
You want to click on the `raw` link on that page, at the top of the code window on the right, to get the csv by itself.

```
import pandas as pd

data_url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_time_series/time_series_covid19_confirmed_global.csv'  

data = pd.read_csv(data_url)

print(data.head())
```